# Instagram API not working

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am working with instagram API to fetch instagram images in php.It was working till 2 weeks before. Now it shows some   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST  error.I am using file_get_contents() methode to get images. Does instagram made some API updation? or I should make the Client Info to live? What must be the problem? If it has to be live, how can i do that?

Comment: Platform updates took hold on June 1st. https://www.instagram.com/developer/platform_update/

Comment: The new app must be submitted for their approval? or i can get sanbox testing after migration? i could not do like that. does Video Screencast URL also mandatory one?